# How to capture user reply from Hero card in Microsoft bot v4

Tags: c#, botframework

I want to capture the user reply after clicking on one of the options on the hero card in Microsoft bot v4.
Could you please help me?
Thanks

```
var card777 = new HeroCard
{
    //Text = "Could you please click on the below button to continue?",
    Buttons = new List<CardAction>
    {
        new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, title: "Yes", value: "contain"),
        new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, title: "No", value: "Does not contain"),
    },
};

var reply777 = MessageFactory.Attachment(card777.ToAttachment());
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply777, cancellationToken);
```

After the hero card will be displayed in the chat, user will select one of the card actions.
Then i want to capture that selected value in the answer variable so that i can do further manipulation with the answer variable

```
  /*  if (answer = "contain")
    {
        countAccessRequest = 1;

    }
    else
    {

        countAccessRequest = 4;
        startAccessRequestFlow = false;
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: There's no trick to this. When the user clicks an option, your bot will receive that option as a message activity. There's nothing special you need to do. Since that answer is so simple, I suspect there's more to your question than what you're actually asking. What do you mean by "capture" the user reply? What do you actually want to do? What have you tried so far? What problems are you running into?

Comment: @Kyle Delaney: Hello Kyle, Thanks a lot for your answer
I'm modifying the above code to show what i'm actually looking for
Could you please help me on this?

Comment: I've used this : var Name = turnContext.Activity.text
But its not working

Comment: @Kyle Delaney: or do we need to call the bot controller in-order to get the response?

Comment: Please explain what you mean when you say it's not working and provide screenshots. What is happening? What channel are you using? Are you testing locally in debug mode? There is absolutely no reason an `imBack` shouldn't send a message activity to the bot. Please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#debug-a-c-bot-using-breakpoints-in-visual-studio) so that you know how to debug a bot and so you can see what the value of `turnContext.Activity.Text` is after you click a button.

Comment: @Kyle: 
If i put answer =  turnContext.Activity.text
I should be getting answer = contain but i'm getting an initial text entered at the beginning of the program. Yes i'm testing in the emulator in debug mode.

Comment: @Kyle: Can i send you the code?

Comment: Sending me the code isn't going to help since it sounds like your problem has to do with your understanding of bots and turns. It's very difficult for me to know where your point of confusion is, but the more information you can give me about what you're doing and what you're expecting to happen, the better. Please refer to the documentation to help get a better understanding of bots: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-overview-introduction

Comment: If you do need to send private information then you can email me

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use **ActionTypes.MessageBack** you will be able to catch the **value** from **Activity.Value** in the following way:

```
   var card777 = new HeroCard
        {
            //Text = "Could you please click on the below button to continue?",
            Buttons = new List<CardAction>
             {
            new CardAction(ActionTypes.MessageBack, title: "Yes", value: "contain"),
            new CardAction(ActionTypes.MessageBack, title: "No", value: "Does not contain"),
             },
        };

        if (context.Activity.Value != null)
        {
            // payload will either be "contain" or "does not contain"
            string payload = context.Activity.Value.ToString();
        }
```